# jQuery scrolltop is delayed on scrolling fast

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate, scrolltop

http://jsfiddle.net/dennym/wJc9V/1/

Having a problem with delayed triggering of the else state. If you scroll down and scroll up fast it takes up to 2 seconds until the smaller menubar disappears again. Usually the second menu (pink) should appear at 200 px and the large one (green) disappears in the top. When scrolling back to top it should reverse this state.

Any ideas?

this is the js snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
            jQuery('.onco-nav-small').css({"display":"block", "visibility":"visible"}).animate({marginTop:"0px"},500);
            jQuery('.onco-nav-large').css({"display":"none", "visibility":"hidden"});
        } else {
            jQuery(".onco-nav-small").animate({marginTop:"-50px"},10);
            jQuery('.onco-nav-large').css({"display":"block", "visibility":"visible"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're going to use an animation, you must also either stop the animation, or use a throttle to prevent starting 3000 animations at once. I prefer to not use an animation for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/wJc9V/2/)

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

`.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )` setting it `stop(true,true)` in the else part to clear the complete the previous animation.So that there is no delay in the next animation.

```
jQuery(".onco-nav-small").stop(true,true).animate({marginTop:"-50px"},10);
```